# Is applying ::before to input[type=submit] possible?

Tags: css, forms, submit, submit-button

Let's say you have a form input button that you want to style with CSS, but you also want to use "::before" to append text before the styling. How would you do that? Is that even possible?

**input[type=submit]::before {}**   (this doesn't work)

Is editing "value='blahblahbuttontext'" in the form the only way to achieve this?

Thanks,

-- MP

Answer (score 1):

No, pseudo elements don't work on inputs. You can achieve such an effect using javascript, or you can use pure CSS but you will need to replace the input with a button.

```css
[type="submit"]:before{
  content: "blahblah";
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">buttontext</button>
```

Comment: Wow, fast reply. Thanks! And sorry for the duplicate question (I'm new here). I didn't turn up anything in my initial search for an answer. I guess my search criteria was way off.